Sealing knockouts of receptacles/switches and sealing low voltage boxes
I am working to tighten my 1920s house. With respect to junction boxes (receptacles and switches) the common approach seems to be sealing the gap between the box and the wall with spray foam and/or caulking and optionally adding a gasket.
However, there are still holes into the junction box: Knockout through which the cables enter and other small holes. Various sources explicitly say not to put spray foam into junction boxes. But since there is still a small gap between a switch paddle and the case as well as receptacles (even if only the holes) I don't understand what's the point.
Is it really not necessary to seal the gaps/knockouts in a junction box itself? If no, why not? If yes, how? Is a bit of spray foam permissible? For example a bit spray around the gaps and where romex wires enter the box?
To clarify, I mean all the gaps and small holes in the junction box itself. They are far from airtight. As an example, this is a metal junction box in my attic (but plastic boxes have the integrated clamps that let air through):


Of course, the extreme is a low voltage ring because that goes straight into the wall cavity. This shows an example of a low voltage ring (installed CAT6 cabling) next to a receptacle:

What is the right way to seal these?

If you still have knob+tube and small (by modern standards) junction boxes, I’d ask how this project fits into the larger plan, which is usually, ‘make all that old wiring go away’. If that later phase is soon, maybe skip the foam and just use gaskets.

@AloysiusDefenestrate no, I rewired everything already. No KT left.

Generic 1-part spray foam out of a can is basically napalm, so I wouldn't recommend its use anywhere near an electrical box or anywhere fire safety is a consideration, e.g. North America lol.
They do make firestop putty/ caulk that are used e.g. inside conduit to turn the conduit into a fire stop.   That would be fine for small screw holes.
They also make firestop foam, but I would be careful with that stuff and give it an outdoor "flame test" to satisfy yourself as to its non-flammability. It's important to note that conduit fire blocking foam is designed to stop air movement carrying fumes and fire, NOT designed to be a fire-stop material all by itself.  But give it a flame test and see its performance with your own eyes.
You could also try foil tape.
For "wish boxes" (boxes you wish had a back), commonly used for data cables, feel free to replace with proper boxes with cable clamps.
If a whole knockout is missing, they make knockout seals in every size that cost a few pennies.
The cables going into a box will be protected by the UL listed cable clamp which is approved for the cable they were used with.
They make retrofit cable clamps designed to be installed after the wire.

Ok, so Loctite say, I should not put INTO the box but sealing a larger gap outside (between wall and box) should be fine? All KO's are properly sealed and only UL listed clamps used. HOWEVER, my question is about the gaps BETWEEN the wire and clamps (for example, the one in your link has many holes and lets air through but the same applies generally). Or the edges of a metallic box which is all air gap. Or the plastic flanges which do not air seal completely. And lastly, how would you deal with the LV ring which is just a huge gaping hole behind the cover plate?

I see there seems to be special spray foam for that purpose, e.g. https://www.homedepot.com/p/3M-12-oz-Orange-Paintable-High-Heat-Resistant-Specialty-Sealant-FB-Foam/203281270 Can this be used instead inside or outside of an electrical box?

I actually edited my question, clarified this and added pictures. Would be amazing if you could comment on so I can accept answer.

@divB OK, likewise.

You could also try foil tape. Exactly what I was thinking. Key is real metal foil tape and not "tape that looks shiny".

@divB -- I would rely on a firestop putty instead of a "fireblock foam" for this purpose.  (the latter are designed to block hot gases and smoke movement, and don't really need much for ignitability resistance as a result)

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Does Nashua 558CA work as “foil tape”? Would have ton of this at home

@ThreePhaseEel is this https://www.homedepot.com/p/3M-10-1-fl-oz-Red-Fire-Barrier-CP-25WB-Plus-Sealant-CP25WB-10/100166701 the right firestop ?

@divB thats a firestop caulk, not a putty

Something more like this tape from Amazon I know I have purchased name-brand varieties from Home Depot in the past, but am having trouble finding specific examples at the moment. But basically a foil tape with a paper backing. You peel off the paper and are left with literally a thin sheet of foil (thicker than normal kitchen foil but still relatively thin) with a strong adhesive. No fibers or cloth or anything else. Effectively putting a layer of metal on your metal box. But I wouldn't worry about those little holes in most situations.

@ThreePhaseEel I really have a hard time finding this at Ace or HD. Do you have an example of what would be the right thing? In the store they referred me to “GB Liquid Elecrtrical Tape” . Is this the right thing? Or can be used in place of it at least?

@divB -- no, that's a whole different thing.  For an example of firestopping putty, see here.  (I have no affiliation with supplyhouse.com.)
